# Dynamic datasource.json in loopback

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, loopback

I am using loopback with nodejs.

In my datasource.json file i have a connection Settings

```
"mongoConnector": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "DB",
    "password": "",
    "name": "mongoConnector",
    "user": "",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
```

I have a global config json file which contains db connection settings like pwd, host ...

Is there any way to modify mongoConnector dynamically according to global config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a .js configuration file for this. You can create either a `server/datasources.local.js` (will always take precedence over other config files). Or you can use a `NODE_ENV` environment variable to specify a different suffix (i.e. `datasources.{NODE_ENV}.js`). In the file, just export an object that contains your configuration. You can use `process.env.FOO` to get environment variables. You could also `require()` your global file inside the .js config file, and pull from there. It's up to you.

You can find some more info on the [LB docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Environment-specific-configuration.html).